# Why PostgreSQL is not accepting while group by on one table and selecting towards another tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL version
 PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-22ubuntu5) 4.7.2, 64-bit,my question is am joining two tables,Let name it as temp1 and temp2 ,here i need to join this two table

Table structure is

```
marks_map
marks   int
stud_id  int

student
stud_id int
class_id int
```

here my query

```
select class_id,stud_id,count(marks) 
from student as s 
inner join marks_map as m on (s.stud_id=m.stud_id) group by stud_id
```

Here i get error as

```
ERROR:  column "s.class_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Why does this error happen? If I use `class_id` in `group by` it's running successfully.

Comment: That's how Group By works: if you don't Group By class_id  how would it know which of multiple class_id values you wanted?

Comment: Hi,in my actual query i need to join more then 3 tables,this query is for showing i get a bug like this.

Comment: You probably also want `sum(marks)`, not `count(marks)`, by the way.

Comment: This has nothing to do with how many tables are joined. You can only mention in the `select` clause columns that you've grouped by, or aggregate functions like `sum`, `count`, `min`, etc. Mentioning other columns makes no logical sense.

Comment: It's ***not*** a bug. This is how `GROUP BY` works in a SQL database. (don't be fooled by the way MySQL handles that - it doesn't complain and simply returns random results in case `GROUP BY` isn't used properly). Maybe you should tell us what output you expect, then we can suggest a solution to the real problem.

Comment: Is `stud_id` the primary key of `student`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the class_id attribute to your group by clause because in your select part of the statement there is no aggregation function over this attribue.

In **GROUP BY** statments you have to add all the attributes over which you haven't aggregated after the **GROUP BY** clause.

For example:

```
SELECT
non-aggregating-attr-1, non-aggregating-attr2, non-aggregating-attr3, sum(attr4)
FROM
table
GROUP BY
non-aggregating-attr-1, non-aggregating-attr2, non-aggregating-attr3
```

Comment: @micro.widmer,yes you are correct,why this so? Their is any other way which will lead me to select a column which is not used in group by and aggregate function

Comment: As others already commented, that's the way `GROUP BY` works. What exactly doesn't work as you expect/need it?

Comment: @mirco.widmer Well, if there's more than one `class_id` for a given `student_id`, what do you want it to do? Pick one at random and show it? (If so, you want `DISTINCT ON`; see the PostgreSQL manual). Or list all student ID / class ID combinations - in which case you must `GROUP BY` both student ID and class ID?

Comment: If there is more than one `class_id` for a given `student_id`, then there is another problem because the `marks_map` doesn't include the class_id. Daniel Vérité described the problem pretty good. The problem is in the database design.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way `group by` work.

You can check your data like

```
select
    array_agg(class_id) as arr_class_id,
    stud_id, count(marks) 
from student as s 
   inner join marks_map as m on (s.stud_id=m.stud_id)
group by stud_id
```

and see how much class_id you have for each group. Sometimes your class_id is dependant from stud_id (you have only one elemnet in array for each group), so you can use dummy aggregate like:

```
select
    max(class_id) as class_id,
    stud_id, count(marks) 
from student as s 
   inner join marks_map as m on (s.stud_id=m.stud_id)
group by stud_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to understand the problem on a simplified case that doesn't even involve a JOIN.

The query `SELECT x,[other columns] GROUP BY x` expresses the fact that for **every distinct value of `x`**, the [other columns] must be output **with only one row for every `x`**.

Now looking at a simplified example where the `student` table has two entries:

> stud_id=1, class_id=1
>   stud_id=1, class_id=2

And we ask for `SELECT stud_id,class_id FROM student GROUP BY class_id`.

There is only one distinct value of `stud_id`, which is 1.

So we're telling the SQL engine, *give me one row with `stud_id=1` and the value of `class_id` that comes with it*. And the problem is that there is not one, but two such values, 1 and 2. So which one to choose? Instead of choosing randomly, the SQL engine yields an error saying the question is conceptually bogus in the first place, because there's no rule that says *each distinct value of `stud_id` has its own corresponding `class_id`*.

On the other hand, if the non-GROUP'ed output columns are aggregate functions that transform a series of values into just one, like `min`, `max`, or `count`, then they provide the missing rules that say how to get only one value from several. That's why the SQL engine is OK with, for instance: `SELECT stud_id,count(class_id) FROM student GROUP BY stud_id;`.

Also, when faced with the error *column "somecolumn" must appear in the GROUP BY clause*, you don't want to just add columns to the `GROUP BY` until the error goes away, as if it was purely a syntax problem. It's a semantic problem, and each column added to the GROUP BY changes the sense of the question submitted to the SQL engine.

That is, `GROUP BY x,y` means **for each distinct value of the (x,y) couple**. It does not mean `GROUP BY x`, and hey, since it leads to an error, let's throw in the `y` as well!